# AmCharts - How to create gaps in a line chart if Im loading external data

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using AmCharts v2. I need to create gaps in a line chart, but I dont know how to if I am loading external data(d3). I found a way to create it manually, but it doesnt work if im getting the data from a file that already has all the data. It loads like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePlJS.png
As you can see, the gap would be from 17 to 21.

And this is the part of the code that get the data and place in the chart to create it, where I think the gap code will be:

```
//Create a scale of a graphic

valueAxis[i] = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
valueAxis[i].axisColor = colors[i - 1];
valueAxis[i].axisThickness = 2;
valueAxis[i].gridAlpha = 0;
valueAxis[i].offset = i * 20;
chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis[i]);

graphics[i] = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graphics[i].valueAxis = valueAxis[i];
graphics[i].title = d;
graphics[i].valueField = d;
graphics[i].bullet = "round";
graphics[i].hideBulletsCount = 30;
graphics[i].bulletBorderThickness = 1;
chart.addGraph(graphics[i]);
```

Comment: there shouldn't be a gap? what exactly is the problem? you give data to amcharts and they create the graphs, there is a gap because no data is there.

Comment: The line connecting the point from day 16 to day 22. I dont want it to be created. Like this one: https://puu.sh/sEjt7/c54c07448b.png But then again, the way they created that gap is manually, I cant do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set `connect` to false:

```
"connect": false,
```

See this fiddle, with `"connect": false`: http://jsfiddle.net/bs8ow9gr/

And the same code, with "`connect: true`: http://jsfiddle.net/4dd9w2q5/